# Symfony4 & Doctrine: Join does not work

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying Symfony4, Doctrine & PgSQL
I have Customers which have many Users, i have a login page and a profile page (which only dump $user logged and $user->getCustomer())

Database contains:
customers:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  2 | Customer 1 |
+----+------------+
```

users:

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | customer_id | username |                           password                           | is_active |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 |           2 | root     | $2y$12$s.J4LbCNSKk6dssRrS2yteBGpQT192JvayICEv9zVfax3DykvR5yW | t         |
+----+-------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

When i'm log in, and go to /profile, i can see the user:

```
User {#81545 ▼
  -id: 1
  -username: "root"
  -password: "$2y$12$s.J4LbCNSKk6dssRrS2yteBGpQT192JvayICEv9zVfax3DykvR5yW"
  -isActive: true
  -customer: Customer {#81604 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    -id: 2
    -name: null
    -users: null
     …2
  }
}
```

But the customer's name is null.
Why in customer object the id is correctly set but the others fields are not ?
And how can i retrieve the "full" object

The controller look like:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profile")
     */
    public function profile(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('admin/home.html.twig', array(
                    'me' => $this->getUser(),
                    'customer' => null,
        ));
    }
```

But i update the controller to (only add $customerRepository->findOneBy)

```
    /**
     * @Route("/profile")
     */
    public function profile(\App\Repository\CustomerRepository $customerRepository): Response
    {
        $unused = $customerRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $this->getUser()->getCustomer()->getId()]);

    return $this->render('admin/home.html.twig', array(
                'me' => $this->getUser(),
                'customer' => null,
    ));
}
```

Now the customer field is correctly set.
I don't understand

Here the twig template of the profile page:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    <b>Authenticated !</b><br/>
    {{ dump(me) }}
    {{ dump(me.customer) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here customer implementation:

```
namespace App\Accounting;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers",schema="test")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer implements \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="customer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // all setters & getters
}
```

And User:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users",schema="test")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $customer;

    // all setters & getters

    public function eraseCredentials()
    { 
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
                // see section on salt below
                // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                // see section on salt below
                // $this->salt
                ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [lazy loading](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects).
It means that the relations of your obejcts are not initialized until you don't require them. It's used to optimize memory and database request. You can see the ID set but also `+__isInitialized__: false`. First time you'll require the customer by your `$user->getCustomer()` method the orm will execute the query to retrieve the object.

In twig template you can use the properties even if they are private as in your case.

So add a this to your user class

```
public function getCustomer(){
    return $this->customer;
}
```

And whenever you need the "customer" object get it using the method.